# SAGEM XG-760A/N on linux

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, wireless-adapter

Will it work ??

EDIT

I bumped into link:

http://www.modem-help.co.uk/Sagem/XG760A-USB-Dongle-WiFi.html

Do you think that this page lies or tells truth?

Comment: Do you have vendor and product IDs?

Comment: It's in the topic.

Comment: No they aren't. That's the model name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZD1211 drivers have been in the kernel for at least a year or so now.

Comment: You have to install zd1211-firmware to even list access points though, and even then it doesn't connect to anything - on Raspberry-pi at least.

Answer (score 1):

In case you use a kernel which doesn't include ZD1211 drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install zd1211-firmware
```

You can get more details if needed in this blog post:
http://xmeblog.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/raspberry-pi-using-usb-dongle-sagem-xg.html

Comment: Half-works. It will not actually connect, just scan.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know too much about Linux but I believe it would still need the correct drivers. No drivers listed here: http://driverscollection.com/?H=XG760A%20Dongle%20WiFi&By=Sagem